# Force wordpress to request for FTP Info on theme/plugin install/update

Tags: plugins, themes, updates

Is it possible to force wordpress to **always** request for FTP credentials when installing and updating plugins / themes? I know the ftp credentials input is bypassed if wordpress has enough unix user access, but i want wordpress to ask nevertheless. Is this possible? How?

Comment: I don't give this as an answer because it might cause some issue with cache plugins but in your case you could just change `/wp-content/` rights. It the server does not have write permissions it will ask for credentials

Comment: remove write access to `/wp-content/`? It will break media uploads too, won't it? And some other plugins/themes need write access to certain files for dynamic .css for example

Comment: My goal is just to make sure a user has FTP credentials first before uploading anything on the wp admin.. (I would have disabled theme editor already, so the only thing left is the wp theme/plugin install)

Comment: I wouldn't edit my theme via wp-admin anyway so I really don't need it..

Comment: no there's maybe /upgrade/ too, be careful with this technique anyway or wait for an answer

Comment: @JMa Thanks for the time though.. i've got an answer now.. I just want to do this so that those people who could brute force my wp-admin still can't do anything. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this on a local install that previously used the 'direct' FS_METHOD.

In `wp-config.php`, set the following constants:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
```

Not sure if this actually affects things, but I also set these to try to force the input fields to be empty when the form is presented:

```
define('FTP_USER', false);
define('FTP_PASS', false);
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants

Comment: Hi, it's working alright, but why do you need to specifically put `define('FTP_USER', false);` and `define('FTP_PASS', false);`? I tested just adding `define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');` and it works already.. But since i've got the idea from you.. you get the credits. thanks!

Comment: Now I wonder why people don't use this for security purposes.. o.O?

Comment: I think if you just don't add them it'll still work. I added them to try to explicitly force the fields to be empty when the form is presented to the user.

Comment: maybe you can edit it to specify that it is optional? well. thanks a lot.